# Allow backslash regex

Tags: php, regex

I've a function which replace characters in PHP:

```
$texte = preg_replace('`\[math\](.+)\[/math\]`isU', '\( $1 \)', $texte);
```

But I would allow the `\` because my strings look like that :  `\frac{5}{2 \sqrt{5} } x_{k}`

**EDIT 1 :**
For example, the user write the following BBcode : `[math] \frac{5}{2 \sqrt{5} } x_{k} [math]` it will be translated in HTML by : `\( \frac{5}{2 \sqrt{5} } x_{k} \)`

**EDIT 2 :**
This is the function:

```
$result = preg_replace('`\[math\](.*)\[/math\]`isU', '\( $1 \)', $text);
```

With `$text = "[math] \frac{5}{2 \sqrt{5} } x_{k} [/math]";` It returns `\( frac{5}{2 sqrt{5} } x_{k} \)` 
The `\` has disappeared.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Double backslash?  (eg \\)

Comment: Your regex looks like its for bbcode, did you copy the wrong stuff ?

Comment: `(?<!\\)what you search for here` ?

Comment: `\\ ` is what your looking for

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I've just edited the topic and I've added an example.

Comment: @sln Yes it's BBcode. What would you mean by "did you copy the wrong stuff ?" ?

Comment: The conversion you're showing only replaces the `[math]` blocks with `\(` and `\)`, you're not touching anything inside the math statement, so `.*` should work just fine. What are you actually seeing as a result when you run this? (show us the code you're using, the test data you ran through it, and the result that gave you)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Topic edited.

Comment: @louis67 No it doesn't. On a plain PHP with the test string and the code you provided, the result is `\(  rac{5}{2 \sqrt{5} } x_{k}  \)`. That's not 100% correct, but also nothing like what you're showing. Change the string to single quoted, and we get `\(  \frac{5}{2 \sqrt{5} } x_{k}  \)` which is exactly what you want. Your code works just fine.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes, excuse me. I've forgot to precise that the result I've shown is the result after MathJax conversion, it returns actually `\( frac{5}{2 sqrt{5} } x_{k} \)` Just the backslash have disappeared

Comment: Right, so the problem is you're losing the \ because of string interpretation (remember `"..."` means anything with \ gets interpreted as a control code, so \n becomes a newline, \t a tab, etc. and anything with $ gets interpreted as a variable that needs substituting). Your regexp is just fine.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans So is there a solution to don't interpret the backslash or is it just impossible ?

Comment: if the data comes from some real source, such as parsing the data from an HTTP request, then this is simply not an issue. If, however you're testing with hardcoded strings, use single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found, I have to use

```
$texte = preg_replace('`\[math\](.*)\[/math\]`isU', '\( $1 \)', $texte);
```

But I've put this to show $texte : `echo'<td>'.BBcode(nl2br(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($data['post_texte'])))).'`

I have just to remove the `stripslashes` function like this :

`echo'<td>'.BBcode(nl2br(htmlspecialchars($data['post_texte']))).'`

And it's work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
$text = '[math] \frac{5}{2 \sqrt{5} } x_{k} [/math]';
$result = preg_replace('`\[math\](.*)\[/math\]`isU', '( $1 )', $text);
echo "result=$result<br>";
```

Note I've put the input string in single quotes, so the backslashes don't get interpreted as anything, and you didn't want the backslashes in the replacement string. Hope this is what you want.